# My algorithm doesn't work

Tags: algorithm

Im pretty new to Android but I have worked with Java before.

I dont understand why my algorithm doesn't work. The result I get is 0.0%.

```
txtInfo.setText(Double.toString((RadioProgress/255)*100)+"%");
```

txtInfo is a TextView.
I can see in my graphic that my RadioProgress gets the right value. But still I get 0.0% all the time.

Please help me understand :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems that `RadioProgress` is integer. Cast it to `float`/`double`.

Comment: `String.valueOf(…)` would evade one instantiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `RadioProgress` is of `integer` type and less than `255` then division will always return `0`. Cast it to double and you will see values.

Another way would be to divide by `255.0` to enforce conversion

```
txtInfo.setText(Double.toString((RadioProgress/255.0)*100)+"%");
```

Comment: @nia glad to hear that! Feel free to accept the answer in that case